# Custom Dialog for no internet access

Tags: android, dialog

I want to create dialog box similar to this image, can anyone help me out[image]

Comment: Everything about Dialogs (including illustrations and code): http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 1):

You can create an alert dialog to do this. Something like this should work.

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
        .setTitle("Connection Failed")
        .setMessage("Please Check Your Internet Connection")
        .setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                   //Code for try again 
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                }
            }).create();
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a reference on how to build dialogs

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Here is a code snippet that should help you detecting internet access:

http://www.androidsnippets.org/snippets/131/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check connection, for that add following class.
Class ConnectionDetector:

```
  public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

then check result of ConnectionDetector and show the Alert Dialog .